# audacity recording monitor sound plus microphone

Tags: linux, record, monitor, microphone, audacity

i would like to record my monitor-sound (e.g. musicplayer) and microphone with [audacity 2.4.2](https://www.audacityteam.org/audacity-2-4-2-released/) under [pop!_OS 21.04](https://pop.system76.com/). i am using the u-phoria [umc202hd](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0BJZ) (i use the third soundcard U192k).

**do you know a way to record monitor sound and microphone with audacity simultaneously on linux?**

[image: settings gnome audio]

```
❯ uname -a
Linux vl 5.13.0-7620-generic #20~1634827117~21.04~874b071-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 29 15:06:55 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

❯ sudo apt install pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils pavucontrol -y

❯ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x8d118000 irq 139
 1 [Dock           ]: USB-Audio - USB-C Triple-4K Dock
                      DisplayLink USB-C Triple-4K Dock at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, super speed
 2 [C525           ]: USB-Audio - HD Webcam C525
                      HD Webcam C525 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4.2, high speed
 3 [U192k          ]: USB-Audio - UMC202HD 192k
                      BEHRINGER UMC202HD 192k at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4.4, high speed
```

Answer (score -1):

That is two separate operations.  In Linux, it is possible to use loopback recording to get a copy of what is currently going out the speakers.  Start looking here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound

Comment: thank you for your feedback. when i open pavucontrol there is no device for recording. **how can i set an alsa plugin [audacity]?**

[image about pavucontrol for recording and missing alsa plugin][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDKDL.png

Comment: Was there an application sending audio when you took that screenshot?